# Vertical Align in Span Doesn't Work?

Tags: html, css, inline, vertical-alignment

**I don't think is exact scenario is answered elsewhere. Please don't close it...**
I want the span to be centered vertically using vertical align. Even though it is an inline element the `vertical-align` property doesn't seem to work.
Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeq8R/).

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <span>Text</span> 
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    background: pink;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px; }

span {
    vertical-align: middle; }
```

Comment: Because vertical-align doesn't work on inline elements.  Change the display of your span to `inline-block`, and / or use `line-height` as @Deepika suggests.

Comment: span {
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height:60px;
}   Put this in your code.

Comment: @Deepika - the `vertical-align` won't do anything.  The line-height will, so why have `vertical-align` at all?

Comment: @Deepika I believe I've seen in many examples that vertical align DOES in fact work on inline elements?

Comment: Am sorry, my mistake, remove the vertical-align from the code.

Comment: It doesn't.  Use `line-height`, `padding`, or some other method.  But it simply doesn't, as your fiddle proves.

Comment: Yes, but I had been through same problem in which vertical-align did not work, line-height solved my problem.

Comment: Add these styles `div { display: table }` `span { display : table-cell }`

Comment: I will be using the same amount of padding from top and bottom then.

Comment: `vertical-align` on inline-level elements (like `<span>` is by default) works fine. It just doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: add this code `span {
  line-height: 60px;
    vertical-align: middle; }`